# jQuery datepicker need long press to open in iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone

How can I make it to open the datepicker in just one tap in iPhone?

In desktop and Android it's just fine; only in iPhone do I need to long-press or tap it many times.

This is my script:

```
jQuery(".calendar-pick").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd M, yy',minDate: 0});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var pressTimer;
//put below click if resolution is IPHONE long press on anchor link or textbox it will open after 2 secs 
$(".calendar-pick, a").mouseup(function(){
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
  // Clear timeout
  return false;
}).mousedown(function(){
  // Set timeout
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
  //your code goes here first
    $(".calendar-pick").datepicker("destroy");
    $(".calendar-pick").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd M, yy',minDate: 0});
    $(".calendar-pick").focus();
  
  },2000);
  return false; 
});

$(function(){
$(".calendar-pick").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd M, yy',minDate: 0});
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a href="#" >Hello</a>
<input  class="calendar-pick" type="text" />
```

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization ohh that's cool post your answer as well for future references

Comment: done posting bdw thanks again to your answer i got a clue

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization you are always welcome but i have small question in your answer on click it will immediately open datepicker that's what you wants?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".calendar-pick").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).focus();
});
```

base on **Curiousdev** answer i just make it shorter